# Server-side rendering with React - confused about whether we still need templates or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-dom, react-dom-server

I was looking at this project
https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example

I opened this issue
https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example/issues/25

Do we need to still use HTML template files? ... or can we just use React components on the backend, and render like so:

```
res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Comp items={items}/>));
```

does React allow `<html> <body> and <head>` tags?

If so I could just create a parent React component that can act as the template, like so:

```
const React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({

     render: function(){

      return (

          <html lang="en">
          <head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
                  <title>Title</title>
          </head>
          <body>

              {this.props.body}

          </body>
          </html>

      )

   } 

});
```

what is the right way to do this?

Comment: No needs for template here. Create can handle html/head/body tag just fine in server rendering

Comment: thanks! do you think you could answer this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320590/server-side-rendering-with-react-composability-passing-child-component-to-p

Comment: Oop. I mean *React instead of *Create

Comment: The answer is yes. Check out this: https://github.com/WebbyLab/itsquiz-wall/blob/master/server/app.js :)

Comment: @Nico "yes" to which question? It's unclear.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you don't need template files anymore. The example I linked utilizes html code inline, but just renders the pages server side before sending it to the browser